# Trouble printing desired output

Tags: python

> ### Instructions
>
> Write a program in `main.py` that prints the same notes from the previous lesson using what you have learnt about the Python `print` function.
>
> **Warning:** The output in your program should match the example output shown below exactly, character for character, even spaces and symbols should be identical, otherwise the tests won't pass.
>
> ### Example Output
>
> After you have written your code, you should run your program and it should print the following:
>
> ```
> Day 1 - Python Print Function
> ```
>
> The function is declared like this:
>
> ```
> print('what to print')
> ```

My problem is I put in the code exactly as it says, then when I try to run it, it's is telling me the issue is with the `1`. I don't understand how it could be the issue.

This is what I typed in exactly:

```
Day 1 - Python Print Function
The function is declared like this:
print('what to print')
```

I've tried to play around with it a little, changing the lower or upper letters as well as changing the `'` to `"`, even changing spacing, but nothing has worked even when I've typed it in exactly how it asked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Terrible title, no code, no clear question... please see [ask]

Comment: `Day 1 - Python Print Function` was not intended to be actual code.  I think that is the message that the assignment is asking you to print.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a programming language; a Python file is very different from a text file containing English sentences. That may seem obvious, but consider if I saved the following as a file and tried to run it as Python:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

It would not print that sentence; I would instead get a syntax error, because that file is not valid Python code. Now, look at what you've saved as a file:

```
Day 1 - Python Print Function
The function is declared like this:
print('what to print')
```

The *last line* of that is indeed valid Python, but the Python interpreter has no idea what to do with everything before it. These three lines are not your *program*; the first line (`Day 1 - Python Print Function`) is *what your program is supposed to print*, and the rest is a hint on how to do so. (Thanks to John Gordon for helping to clear this up in the comments.)

Now, while you were tinkering around and changing things, did you happen to try running just that last line? If you run just this:

```
print('what to print')
```

Your command line interpreter (or IDE of choice) should print out this output:

```
what to print
```

Do you see how you might be able to change that to get the actual output you want?

Comment: I guess Thats the main issue I know that the print('what to print') part is right but the course is asking me to input everything above that exactly as written also. I'm thinking the instructor just wanted me to type print('what to print') only but because they made a mistake by putting the rest of the above text in as the answer, so it's going to be incorrect no matter what I put in because of how she input the correct answer.

Comment: You want it to *output* exactly that. Which means you need to supply it as the argument to `print()`, not just stick it in your file.